# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, express, backend

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959   throw err;  ^


Error: Cannot find module '../controllers/coursecontrollers'
Require stack:
- /project/E_Learning_Backend/routes/CourseRoute.js
- /project/E_Learning_Backend/app.js
- /project/E_Learning_Backend/server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/project/E_Learning_Backend/routes/CourseRoute.js:2:120)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/project/E_Learning_Backend/routes/CourseRoute.js',
    '/project/E_Learning_Backend/app.js',
    '/project/E_Learning_Backend/server.js'
  ]
}
```

It ruining perfectly on my local machine but when I try to upload it in codeSandbox it gives this error. I try vercel too it gave  this error 404 recourse not found

here is GitHub repo link if you want to see code:-https://github.com/Jainex17/E_Learning_Backend

Answer (score 0):

check the path of your archive

maybe you have write your package.json like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
```

try to specify the module:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node src/app.js"
  },
```